# How to upload an image to the corresponding tenant in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

First time I'm working with multi-tenant, and I have multiple tenants, the thing is that I don't know how to upload to Storage to the corresponding tenant image.

For example:
Tenant 1:
Upload your company logo

Tenant 2:
Upload your own company logo

I'm currently working with tenant 59138 (**storage/app/tenancy/tenants/59138/[here add *image folder*]**

[image: Tenants]

**Config Filesystems**

```
'tenancy' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => storage_path('app/tenancy/tenants/'),
],
```

**Controller**

```php
public function storeImage(Request $request){
     //dd($request->all());
     if ($request->file('logo')) {
        $fileLogo = $request->file('logo');
            
        $path = Storage::disk('tenancy')->put('public',$fileLogo);
        
     }
}
```

Comment: correct me if am wrong, but i think there is a better approach to what your trying to do, you could have a db table for images. it will relate all uploaded images with the uploader or else there is a different reason for wanting the images in specific folders other than to relate an image to the uploader

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request){

    $File = $request->file('data'); 

    //First Parameter is the Folder Name and Second Parameter is the File Object
    $stored = \Storage::disk('public')->put("your_folder_name", $File);
    $url = tenant_asset($stored);
    return response()->json(['success' =>$url], 200);

}
```

Comment: Thank you Aman, when answer please explain the code, a code snippet may lack context to understand.

Comment: The first line is just reading the File from your request object i.e the file that is being uploaded (the name of the form element which holds your file = 'data' )
After that, we are just storing the file in whichever folder you want. 
This is also tenant specific so it will be stored in the `storage\tenant_id\app\public\your_folder_name`
And After that we are returning the Public URL to that file so that it can be viewed or downloaded

Answer (score 0):

if someone using version 3

**tenant_asset()** use this controller to return the response of any file after validate it's a valid one `/vendor/stancl/tenancy/src/Controllers/TenantAssetsController.php`

I face problem for that function it redirect me back or throw an error because of middleware, they are using this middleware

```
 public static $tenancyMiddleware = 'Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain';
```

after I changed to that one using same custom controller it works !

```
public static $tenancyMiddleware = 'Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomainOrSubdomain';
```