# Multi tenant plus Storage facade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, multi-tenant

Since I started with multi tenant, I'm having problems getting the url path for images

My tenants can upload an image. Lets say its the logo
With multi tenant it saved the folders like in this image:

https://prnt.sc/wXMQc1zjHErI

I save the file using the following line code:

```
$path = request()->file("file")->store('public');
```

Its automatic the generation of the tenant folder, the documentation explains that:
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v2/filesystem-tenancy/

I save the path at my database. It saves a line as the following example:

```
public/JwsCeCCxgKiM8ZVYAMNt9gPJeZKDsb8NUKmPzak8.jpg
```

Now I want to get the URL of that file, in order to load the logo in my front application:

```
private function getLogoPath(){
        if($this->logo == null)
            return null;
            
        return Storage::url($this->logo);
    }
```

It is impossible to load that, because it will return the path stored in the database

If I try to do: localhost:8000/ returned_path

Its not working because I cant find any image

It was working without multi tenant. Now I'm having troubles because of multi tenancy

Tried already with

```
private function getLogoPath(){
    if($this->logo == null)
        return null;

    return asset(Storage::url($this->logo));
}
```

it returns the message:

```
Tenant could not be identified on domain localhost
```

Can someone help me in order to know what to do or how can I do it?

UPDATE:

With this code I'm able to get the correct path inside my laravel server:

```
private function getLogoPath(){
        if($this->logo == null)
            return null;
        
        //Storage::disk('tenancy')->delete($this->logo);

        return Storage::disk('tenancy')->url($this->logo);
    }
```

I know this because if I run the delete, it deletes the image inside the correct folder.

Now, I need to return an url. Because this is returning to a vuejs api to load the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer, I'm returning the URL

```
private function getLogoPath(){
        if($this->logo == null)
            return null;


        return \URL::to(tenancy()->tenant->id . "/storage/logo/" . $this->id);
    }
```

I use tenancy to identify the tenant where I want to go and then, and this is importantn, I created a controller:

```
class LogoController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request){

        $file = Storage::path($file->logo);

        return response()->file($file);
    }
}
```

And this controller runs inside a tenant, because in the web.php inside the route folder I have this:

```
\Route::name("logo.get")->middleware(["auth", InitializeTenancyByPath::class])
    ->get("{tenant}/storage/logo/{file_id}", "\App\Http\Controllers\LogoController");
```

As we can see, when I return the URL, the front makes another request to the returned URL. That request is executed by that route and, the TENANT is important. Because using the initialization by tenant, we can go inside the tenant storage folder and after that we can work normally

Answer (score 0):

By default, this line

```
$path = request()->file("file")->store('public');
```

saves the file in the directory storage/app/public.
Laravel documentation says:

> (...) all files that should be publicly accessible should be placed in
> the **storage/app/public** directory. Furthermore, you should create a
> symbolic link at **public/storage** which points to the storage/app/public
> directory.

Then the address returned by `Storage::url($this->logo)` will work.

To create symlink you may use Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: correct. But when using multitenancy it saves in storage/TENANT/app/public

Comment: Maybe it would be better to create a table in the database to associate the images with the uploaders? Unique file names can be generated by `$fileName = Str::orderedUuid().'.'.$request->file('image')->extension();` and then the save folder will be only one, with symlink to public? Somebody correct me if I'm thinking wrong.

Comment: but following multi tenancy documentation it does not refer to any data stored in a database. They simple explain the things and it seems pretty easy. Maybe I'm stucked in something really easy, but the truth is that I cant go ahead with this problem

Comment: Hm... maybe see this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803258...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803258/how-to-upload-an-image-to-the-corresponding-tenant-in-laravel)

Comment: tried to use like the link you sent, and I'm getting the problem of tenant unidentified:

Comment: "message": "Tenant could not be identified on domain localhost",